# MVC (PHP): Do Controllers/Actions map to each and every request?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, view, controller

I've been getting to grips with MVC (in PHP) by way of Zend. My understanding of the Zend Framework is that each type of user request maps to a specific controller (which in turn may or may not map to a model), and each action maps to a view. I've noticed the same pattern in Codeigniter and Kohana, and to some extent also in Symfony. Effectively, the URL maps thus:

```
www.domain.com/index.php/CONTROLLER/ACTION/...additional parameters...
```

Is this always the case with MVC? In what way is this different from Page Controller as a design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework uses [Two Step View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html). It's very similar to [MVC](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html). As you can see, theres not so much correspondence between the architecture and the url mapping.
 If you want to learn about likely architectures, read [PoEAA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) by Martin Fowler.

Comment: ZF could be used with an MVC pattern and for the View part it uses a 2 step view pattern

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary difference is that with the Page Controller pattern, you have a separate file for each page of your website. In a typical implementation of MVC in PHP, you can group common actions together in a single controller. Also, the typical MVC implementation in PHP support custom routing allowing you to create custom maps to controllers/actions without the need of using http server rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

1-"Is this always the case with MVC?

www.domain.com/index.php/CONTROLLER/ACTION/...additional parameters..."

No its not always case you can extend the routing to be Domain based (as example )  :

## DOMAIN.TLD/USER  to be USER.DOMAIN.TLD

2-I think but I am not 100% sure that the page controller is subset of  in MVC Pattern 
I mean Page Controller =  the Controller ONLY !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's the most common usage of uris. But there's noting saying that you can't use the MVC pattern with (ir)regular uris. A uri like http://www.domain.tld/?controller=home&action=posts or even http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=MVC would do just fine.

MVC is all about how you structure yourlayers and is not reflected in the uri.